# When operating within the framework known as "Yocto", Is it possible to install a deployed file into a package with a separate recipe?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, packaging, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I want to add a *deployed* file to my rootfs image - i.e. "install" from the deployment location (`build/tmp/deploy/images/...`), and have correct bitbake dependencies to ensure the deployed file is built and deployed first.

I have a third-party recipe that compiles and *deploys* a file (i.e. the file ends up in `/tmp/deploy/images/.../`, and not in the image) and it also inherits the `nopackages` class, which disables all the packaging tasks, so there are no packages created. Therefore I cannot create a `.bbappend` to define `do_install_append()` because the original `.bb` recipe has disabled all packaging tasks.

Is it possible for a separate recipe to install a *deployed* file into one of its own packages? I.e. can `do_install_append()` or `do_install()` safely use something like `install ${DEPLOYDIR}/myfile ${D}/destdir/...`? And if so, how do I make sure the original recipe's deployment task is built first?

Do any examples of this kind of process exist in the reference recipes?

EDIT: as requested, I have included the recipe concerned.

It is `meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-zynq-scr.bb` [GitHub](https://github.com/Xilinx/meta-xilinx/blob/2021.1-integration/meta-xilinx-bsp/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-zynq-scr.bb) which is used to create a deployed `boot.scr` file. This recipe is a third-party recipe and although I can create a `.bbappend` for it I don't see a way to write `do_install_append()` to install `boot.scr` to the image because the base recipe has the line:

```
inherit deploy nopackages
```

Therefore any `install` commands in `do_install_append()` don't actually result in anything being installed into the image, as the resultant package is not installed (or even created in the first place?).

```
SUMMARY = "U-boot boot scripts for Xilinx devices"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

DEPENDS = "u-boot-mkimage-native"

inherit deploy nopackages image-wic-utils

INHIBIT_DEFAULT_DEPS = "1"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE ?= "^$"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_zynqmp = "zynqmp"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_zynq = "zynq"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_versal = "versal"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_microblaze = "microblaze"

KERNELDT = "${@os.path.basename(d.getVar('KERNEL_DEVICETREE').split(' ')[0]) if d.getVar('KERNEL_DEVICETREE') else ''}"
DEVICE_TREE_NAME ?= "${@bb.utils.contains('PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/dtb', 'device-tree', 'system.dtb', d.getVar('KERNELDT'), d)}"
#Need to copy a rootfs.cpio.gz.u-boot as uramdisk.image.gz into boot partition
RAMDISK_IMAGE ?= ""
RAMDISK_IMAGE_zynq ?= "uramdisk.image.gz"

PXERAMDISK_IMAGE ?= "${@'ramdisk.cpio.gz.u-boot' if d.getVar('INITRAMFS_IMAGE') and d.getVar('INITRAMFS_IMAGE').find('initramfs') > 0 else '${RAMDISK_IMAGE}'}"

KERNEL_BOOTCMD_zynqmp ?= "booti"
KERNEL_BOOTCMD_zynq ?= "bootm"
KERNEL_BOOTCMD_versal ?= "booti"
KERNEL_BOOTCMD_microblaze ?= "bootm"

BOOTMODE ?= "sd"
BOOTFILE_EXT ?= ".${SOC_FAMILY}"

#Make this value to "1" to skip appending base address to ddr offsets.
SKIP_APPEND_BASEADDR ?= "0"

DDR_BASEADDR ?= "0x0"
DDR_BASEADDR_microblaze ?= "0x80000000"
PRE_BOOTENV ?= ""

SRC_URI = " \
            file://boot.cmd.sd.zynq \
            file://boot.cmd.sd.zynqmp \
            file://boot.cmd.sd.versal \
            file://boot.cmd.qspi.versal \
        file://boot.cmd.generic \
        file://boot.cmd.ubifs \
            file://pxeboot.pxe \
            "

# Specify a default in case boardvariant isn't available
BOARDVARIANT_ARCH ??= "${MACHINE_ARCH}"
PACKAGE_ARCH = "${BOARDVARIANT_ARCH}"

# On zynqmp-dr, we know we're different so if BOARD is not defined, fall back
# to the SOC_VARIANT_ARCH instead
SOC_VARIANT_ARCH ??= "${MACHINE_ARCH}"
PACKAGE_ARCH_zynqmp-dr = "${@['${BOARDVARIANT_ARCH}', '${SOC_VARIANT_ARCH}'][d.getVar('BOARDVARIANT_ARCH')==d.getVar('MACHINE_ARCH')]}"

inherit image-artifact-names
UENV_TEXTFILE ?= "uEnv.txt"
UENV_MMC_OFFSET_zynqmp ?= "0x200000"
UENV_MMC_OFFSET_zynq ?= "0x2080000"
UENV_MMC_OFFSET_versal ?= "0x200000"
UENV_MMC_OFFSET_microblaze ?= "0x0"

UENV_MMC_LOAD_ADDRESS ?= "${@append_baseaddr(d,d.getVar('UENV_MMC_OFFSET'))}"

UBOOTSCR_BASE_NAME ?= "${PN}-${PKGE}-${PKGV}-${PKGR}${IMAGE_VERSION_SUFFIX}"
UBOOTPXE_CONFIG ?= "pxelinux.cfg"
UBOOTPXE_CONFIG_NAME = "${UBOOTPXE_CONFIG}${IMAGE_VERSION_SUFFIX}"

DEVICETREE_ADDRESS ?= "${@append_baseaddr(d,d.getVar('DEVICETREE_OFFSET'))}"

DEVICETREE_OFFSET_microblaze ?= "0x1e00000"
DEVICETREE_OFFSET_zynqmp ?= "0x100000"
DEVICETREE_OFFSET_zynq ?= "0x2000000"
DEVICETREE_OFFSET_versal ?= "0x1000"

KERNEL_LOAD_ADDRESS ?= "${@append_baseaddr(d,d.getVar('KERNEL_OFFSET'))}"

KERNEL_OFFSET_microblaze ?= "0x0"
KERNEL_OFFSET_zynqmp ?= "0x200000"
KERNEL_OFFSET_zynq ?= "0x2080000"
KERNEL_OFFSET_versal ?= "0x200000"

KERNEL_IMAGE ?= "${KERNEL_IMAGETYPE}"

RAMDISK_IMAGE_ADDRESS ?= "${@append_baseaddr(d,d.getVar('RAMDISK_OFFSET'))}"

RAMDISK_OFFSET_microblaze ?= "0x2e00000"
RAMDISK_OFFSET_zynq ?= "0x4000000"
RAMDISK_OFFSET_zynqmp ?= "0x4000000"
RAMDISK_OFFSET_versal ?= "0x6000000"

FIT_IMAGE_LOAD_ADDRESS ?= "${@append_baseaddr(d,d.getVar('FIT_IMAGE_OFFSET'))}"
FIT_IMAGE_OFFSET ?= "0x10000000"
FIT_IMAGE ?= "image.ub"

## Below offsets and sizes are based on 32MB QSPI Memory for zynq
## For MB
## Load boot.scr at 0xFC0000 -> 15MB of QSPI/NAND Memory
QSPI_KERNEL_OFFSET_microblaze ?= "0xBC0000"
QSPI_KERNEL_SIZE_microblaze ?= "0x500000"
QSPI_RAMDISK_SIZE_microblaze ?= "0xA00000"

## For zynq
## Load boot.scr at 0xFC0000 -> 15MB of QSPI/NAND Memory
QSPI_KERNEL_OFFSET_zynq ?= "0x1000000"
QSPI_RAMDISK_OFFSET_zynq ?= "0x1580000"

NAND_KERNEL_OFFSET_zynq ?= "0x1000000"
NAND_RAMDISK_OFFSET_zynq ?= "0x4600000"

QSPI_KERNEL_SIZE_zynq ?= "0x500000"
QSPI_RAMDISK_SIZE_zynq ?= "0xA00000"

NAND_KERNEL_SIZE ?= "0x3200000"
NAND_RAMDISK_SIZE ?= "0x3200000"

## Below offsets and sizes are based on 128MB QSPI Memory for zynqmp/versal
## For zynqMP
## Load boot.scr at 0x3E80000 -> 62MB of QSPI/NAND Memory
QSPI_KERNEL_OFFSET ?= "0xF00000"
QSPI_KERNEL_OFFSET_zynqmp-dr ?= "0x3F00000"
QSPI_RAMDISK_OFFSET ?= "0x4000000"
QSPI_RAMDISK_OFFSET_zynqmp-dr ?= "0x5D00000"

NAND_KERNEL_OFFSET_zynqmp ?= "0x4100000"
NAND_RAMDISK_OFFSET_zynqmp ?= "0x7800000"

QSPI_KERNEL_SIZE_zynqmp ?= "0x1D00000"
QSPI_RAMDISK_SIZE ?= "0x4000000"
QSPI_RAMDISK_SIZE_zynqmp-dr ?= "0x1D00000"

## For versal
## Load boot.scr at 0x7F80000 -> 127MB of QSPI/NAND Memory
QSPI_KERNEL_OFFSET_versal ?= "0xF00000"
QSPI_RAMDISK_OFFSET_versal ?= "0x2E00000"

NAND_KERNEL_OFFSET_versal ?= "0x4100000"
NAND_RAMDISK_OFFSET_versal ?= "0x8200000"

QSPI_KERNEL_SIZE_versal ?= "0x1D00000"
QSPI_RAMDISK_SIZE_versal ?= "0x4000000"

QSPI_KERNEL_IMAGE_microblaze ?= "image.ub"
QSPI_KERNEL_IMAGE_zynq ?= "image.ub"
QSPI_KERNEL_IMAGE_zynqmp ?= "image.ub"
QSPI_KERNEL_IMAGE_versal ?= "image.ub"

NAND_KERNEL_IMAGE ?= "image.ub"

QSPI_FIT_IMAGE_OFFSET ?= "0x1080000"
QSPI_FIT_IMAGE_SIZE ?= "0x6400000"
QSPI_FIT_IMAGE_SIZE_zynqmp-dr ?= "0x3F00000"
QSPI_FIT_IMAGE_SIZE_zynq ?= "0xF00000"
QSPI_FIT_IMAGE_SIZE_microblaze ?= "0xF00000"

NAND_FIT_IMAGE_OFFSET ?= "0x1080000"
NAND_FIT_IMAGE_SIZE ?= "0x6400000"

SDBOOTDEV ?= "0"

BITSTREAM_LOAD_ADDRESS ?= "0x100000"

do_configure[noexec] = "1"
do_install[noexec] = "1"

def append_baseaddr(d,offset):
    skip_append = d.getVar('SKIP_APPEND_BASEADDR') or ""
    if skip_append == "1":
        return offset
    import subprocess
    baseaddr = d.getVar('DDR_BASEADDR') or "0x0"
    subcmd = "$((%s+%s));" % (baseaddr,offset)
    cmd = "printf '0x%08x' " + str(subcmd)
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8")
    return output

def get_bitstream_load_type(d):
    if boot_files_bitstream(d)[1] :
        return "loadb"
    else:
        return "load"

do_compile() {
    sed -e 's/@@KERNEL_IMAGETYPE@@/${KERNEL_IMAGETYPE}/' \
        -e 's/@@KERNEL_LOAD_ADDRESS@@/${KERNEL_LOAD_ADDRESS}/' \
        -e 's/@@DEVICE_TREE_NAME@@/${DEVICE_TREE_NAME}/' \
        -e 's/@@DEVICETREE_ADDRESS@@/${DEVICETREE_ADDRESS}/' \
        -e 's/@@RAMDISK_IMAGE@@/${RAMDISK_IMAGE}/' \
        -e 's/@@RAMDISK_IMAGE_ADDRESS@@/${RAMDISK_IMAGE_ADDRESS}/' \
        -e 's/@@KERNEL_BOOTCMD@@/${KERNEL_BOOTCMD}/' \
        -e 's/@@SDBOOTDEV@@/${SDBOOTDEV}/' \    
        -e 's/@@BITSTREAM@@/${@boot_files_bitstream(d)[0]}/g' \ 
        -e 's/@@BITSTREAM_LOAD_ADDRESS@@/${BITSTREAM_LOAD_ADDRESS}/g' \ 
        -e 's/@@BITSTREAM_IMAGE@@/${@boot_files_bitstream(d)[0]}/g' \   
        -e 's/@@BITSTREAM_LOAD_TYPE@@/${@get_bitstream_load_type(d)}/g' \   
    -e 's/@@QSPI_KERNEL_OFFSET@@/${QSPI_KERNEL_OFFSET}/' \
    -e 's/@@NAND_KERNEL_OFFSET@@/${NAND_KERNEL_OFFSET}/' \
    -e 's/@@QSPI_KERNEL_SIZE@@/${QSPI_KERNEL_SIZE}/' \
    -e 's/@@NAND_KERNEL_SIZE@@/${NAND_KERNEL_SIZE}/' \
    -e 's/@@QSPI_RAMDISK_OFFSET@@/${QSPI_RAMDISK_OFFSET}/' \
    -e 's/@@NAND_RAMDISK_OFFSET@@/${NAND_RAMDISK_OFFSET}/' \
    -e 's/@@QSPI_RAMDISK_SIZE@@/${QSPI_RAMDISK_SIZE}/' \
    -e 's/@@NAND_RAMDISK_SIZE@@/${NAND_RAMDISK_SIZE}/' \
    -e 's/@@KERNEL_IMAGE@@/${KERNEL_IMAGE}/' \
    -e 's/@@QSPI_KERNEL_IMAGE@@/${QSPI_KERNEL_IMAGE}/' \
    -e 's/@@NAND_KERNEL_IMAGE@@/${NAND_KERNEL_IMAGE}/' \
    -e 's/@@FIT_IMAGE_LOAD_ADDRESS@@/${FIT_IMAGE_LOAD_ADDRESS}/' \
    -e 's/@@QSPI_FIT_IMAGE_OFFSET@@/${QSPI_FIT_IMAGE_OFFSET}/' \
    -e 's/@@QSPI_FIT_IMAGE_SIZE@@/${QSPI_FIT_IMAGE_SIZE}/' \
    -e 's/@@NAND_FIT_IMAGE_OFFSET@@/${NAND_FIT_IMAGE_OFFSET}/' \
    -e 's/@@NAND_FIT_IMAGE_SIZE@@/${NAND_FIT_IMAGE_SIZE}/' \
    -e 's/@@FIT_IMAGE@@/${FIT_IMAGE}/' \
    -e 's/@@PRE_BOOTENV@@/${PRE_BOOTENV}/' \
    -e 's/@@UENV_MMC_LOAD_ADDRESS@@/${UENV_MMC_LOAD_ADDRESS}/' \
    -e 's/@@UENV_TEXTFILE@@/${UENV_TEXTFILE}/' \
    -e 's/@@RAMDISK_IMAGE1@@/${RAMDISK_IMAGE1}/' \
        "${WORKDIR}/boot.cmd.${BOOTMODE}${BOOTFILE_EXT}" > "${WORKDIR}/boot.cmd"
    mkimage -A arm -T script -C none -n "Boot script" -d "${WORKDIR}/boot.cmd" boot.scr
    sed -e 's/@@KERNEL_IMAGETYPE@@/${KERNEL_IMAGETYPE}/' \
        -e 's/@@DEVICE_TREE_NAME@@/${DEVICE_TREE_NAME}/' \
    -e 's/@@RAMDISK_IMAGE@@/${PXERAMDISK_IMAGE}/' \
    "${WORKDIR}/pxeboot.pxe" > "pxeboot.pxe"
}


do_deploy() {
    install -d ${DEPLOYDIR}
    install -m 0644 boot.scr ${DEPLOYDIR}/${UBOOTSCR_BASE_NAME}.scr
    ln -sf ${UBOOTSCR_BASE_NAME}.scr ${DEPLOYDIR}/boot.scr
    install -d ${DEPLOYDIR}/pxeboot/${UBOOTPXE_CONFIG_NAME}
    install -m 0644 pxeboot.pxe ${DEPLOYDIR}/pxeboot/${UBOOTPXE_CONFIG_NAME}/default
    ln -sf pxeboot/${UBOOTPXE_CONFIG_NAME} ${DEPLOYDIR}/${UBOOTPXE_CONFIG}
}

addtask do_deploy after do_compile before do_build
```

Comment: `nopackages` does not remove `do_install`.

Comment: Can you add your two recipes ? al least the `inherit` and `do_deploy` , `do_install` parts of each of the two.

Comment: Sorry - you are right, `do_install` still runs, but how does `do_install` result in anything in the rootfs if there are no packages created by the recipe? I’ll edit my question to add the recipes soon.

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM I have added the script concerned. The file I want to add to my image, _generated_ by this recipe, is `boot.scr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `deploy` class as stated in the Yocto doc:

```
The deploy class handles deploying files to the DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE directory
...
The class then takes care of staging the files from DEPLOYDIR to DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE
```

So, if `u-boot-zynq-scr` installs `boot.scr` to `DEPLOYDIR` which will be populated to `DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE`, then any recipe can access that file.

And since the recipe depends on `u-boot-zynq-scr`'s `do_deploy` spicifically you need to set this in your recipe:

```bash
do_install[depends] = "u-boot-zynq-scr:do_deploy"
do_install(){
    install -d ${D}/anyfolder <==(example)
    install -m 0744 ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/boot.scr ${D}/anyfolder
}
```

When building your main recipe, bitbake will make sure that `do_deploy` of `u-boot-zynq-scr` will be executed and then your recipe will find the file.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and works correctly - thank you for your help.